# Keeping fits files accessibles after closing context manager

Tags: python, with-statement, astropy

I'm opening fits files hosted on some repo with `astropy.io.fits` (fits file format), like so:

```
    for url in self.urllist:
        with fits.open(url) as f:
            l.info(f"Loading file at {url}")
            self.hdu_cal.append(f[1])
```

Basically, I'd like to have a few of them in memory. However, the data become unavailable once I leave the context manager, as the file closes.

Any way to make a copy & ensure that I keep the data in memory?

Comment: Don't use a context manager if you want the object to stay alive.

Comment: oups. I feel a little bit dumb now for not seeing that.

Comment: Maybe say a bit more about what you're trying to do. Do you need the headers or just the data, and what do you plan to do with them? I agree with Barmar that you could just not use the context manager if you want to manage open files yourself. In any case for just reading it's not very important.

Comment: @Iguananaut well I think the question is clear enough. At any rate, I might not need the CM indeed. Although I'd disagree that for reading it's not very important, the point is more about garbage collection, if I'm reading tons of those files into memory but references to those objects remains, eventually runs out of memory...

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of the contents of the object:

```
all_fits = {}
for url in self.urllist:
    with fits.open(url) as f:
        l.info(f"Loading file at {url}")
        all_fits[url] = list(f)
        self.hdu_cal.append(f[1])
```

Comment: That won't work for various reasons.